# Difference between similar sparse structures

Tags: matlab, sparse-matrix

My code works with this kind of structures

```
K>> mlf=sparse([],[],[],2^31+1,1); mlf(1)=1; mlf

mlf =

                  (1,1)                       1
```

but it fails with this kind of inputs below where I choose the terms in mlf that are larger than zero (I cannot understand how this selection makes the input different)

```
K>> mlf=sparse([],[],[],2^31+1,1); mlf(1)=1; mlf(mlf>0)

ans =

   (1,1)        1
```

where the only visual difference is some tabs/spaces.

Please, explain how they are different.

Comment: The first command prints the whole matrix, while the second command prints a slice of it (note that `mlf(mlf>0)` is a new, anonymous variable). My *guess* is that the `disp` of the `sparse` takes into account that the maximum index into it may be `(2147483649,1)`, to which the `disp` adjusts its spacing. The anonymous variable has more information available (such as it being only 1 element long), so *its* `disp` will have less spacing. Just as a general interest: how and why does your code depend on the *displayed* version of a `sparse`?

Comment: Ah nevermind, I misunderstood your question (just refreshed). As I said, `mlf` is a `2147483649x1` sparse with 1 filled value, whereas `mlf(mlf>0)` is a new, anonymous variable of size 1x1 (still `sparse` though). Type `whos ans` after the last command to check this.

Comment: @RodyOldenhuis The command does not show any difference: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19735613/164148

Comment: no, because you're doing something different than before; you're assigning `mlf(mlf>0)` to `mlf`, and not to `ans`...Change all `whos ans` in your version to `whos mlf` and you'll see

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is the size of the resulting array, as Rody suggested:

```
>> mlf=sparse([],[],[],2^31+1,1); mlf(1)=1; size(mlf(mlf>0))
ans =
     1     1
>> mlf=sparse([],[],[],2^31+1,1); mlf(1)=1; size(mlf)
ans =
                2147483649                         1
```

**EDIT 1*: Indexing works properly:

```
>> mlf(mlf>0) = 2
mlf =
                  (1,1)                       2
```

This is functionally equivalent to using `find`:

```
>> mlf(find(mlf)) = 2
mlf =
                  (1,1)                       2
```

It seems like a good conclusion that `display` is formatting the output with enough space for an element at `(2147483649,1)`, **but only when you are indexing for an assignment to that element** (think lvalue vs rvalue).

**EDIT 2*: If you are going after those elements in a full (not sparse) variable, use `full`:

```
>> full(mlf(mlf>0))
ans =
     1
```

**EDIT 3*: To assign to the last element according to the dimensions of `mlf` rather than to the last non-zero element,

```
>> mlf(numel(mlf))=77
mlf =
                  (1,1)                       1
         (2147483649,1)                      77
```

**EDIT 4*: To remove negative values:

```
mlf(mlf<0)=0; % or mlf(find(mlf<0)) = 0;
```

If you want to make a copy and remove the negatives:

```
mlf2 = mlf;
mlf2(mlf2<0) = 0;
mlf3 = mlf;
mlf3(mlf3>0) = 0;
```

Then you have `mlf` with all values, `mlf2` with only positives, and `mlf3` with only negatives. **The key thing with this is that the size stays the same as with the original `mlf` so you are able to use the things such as `end` in the original way based on the size of the sparse, hurray!**

Comment: @hhh I'm confused about the problem then.  It is working as expected.  What should be different?  By the way, you can use `nonzeros(mlf)` if you just want the non-zeros.

Comment: **[Update]** Now I spot my mistake! It is related to `mlf=sparse([],[],[],2^31+1,1); mlf(1)=1; mlf=mlf(mlf>0); mlf(end)=77` where I try to reference so that `mlf(2^31+1)=77` but what it does is actually `mlf(1)=77` -- how should I deal with this? I want that the size of mlf is all the time the same. If the size changes, the `end` result into pecularities...

Comment: @hhh - Interesting. Apparently `end` translates to the index of the last non-zero element, rather than according to the array's dimensions.  If you are going after the last position in terms of size you could do `mlf(numel(mlf))=77` although that seems ugly to me.

Comment: Yet it does not work with `mlf=mlf(mlf>0)` because this changes the size of the `mlf`. I need to keep the size unchanged, ideas? `mlf(numel(mlf))=77` works according to the size: because the `mlf(mlf>0)` changes the size, it does not work with `end` or `numel(mlf)` -- I need to find a way to keep the size unchanged.

Comment: I don't understand how `mlf=mlf(mlf>0)` is related to the `end` indexing issue.  What are you trying to do with `mlf=mlf(mlf>0)`?

Comment: The `mlf=mlf(mlf>0)` gets you all positive numbers but unfortunately changes the size of the structure so that the typical functionality of `end` stops working i.e. referring to `mlf(2^31+1)`. This means that commands that assumes certain size stops working...resulting into odd behaviour.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40406/discussion-between-chappjc-and-hhh)

Answer (score 0):

Rody Oldenhuis recommended the `whos`

```
>> mlf=sparse([],[],[],2^31+1,1); mlf(1)=1; mlf=mlf(mlf>0)

mlf =

   (1,1)        1


>> whos mlf
  Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  mlf       1x1                32  double    sparse    

>> mlf=sparse([],[],[],2^31+1,1); mlf(1)=1; mlf

mlf =

                  (1,1)                       1

>> whos mlf
  Name               Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

  mlf       2147483649x1                32  double    sparse
```

which shows the key problem: the size of the structures have changed. chappjc provided a way to solve this problem by introducing new variables.

Comment: When you do `mlf=sparse([],[],[],2^31+1,1); mlf(1)=1; mlf=mlf(mlf>0); whos ans`, the variable `ans` is not from any of these commands because they are all assignments rather than bare expressions. In this case, who knows what was last assigned to `ans`.

Comment: Feel free to +1 my answer instead.  ;)  The use of `size` is sufficient to show the problem without reassigning `mlf` as in your new first command, but `whos` demonstrates the reason too.

Comment: @chappjc It demonstrates the reason but it does not provide a way to fix it: I am trying to use `mlf>0` as an index for the `mlf`. The mlf is a sparse structure, I cannot see why `mlf(mlf>0)` is not working, thinking... What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Oh, I didn't understand you were looking for a solution.  I think you are indexing `mlf` correctly.  It returns that element of the sparse matrix.  The confusion is that when you do a bare `mlf(mlf>0)` without an assignment, this is like an rvalue, not an lvalue.  If you do `mlf(mlf>0) = 2`, then it will work as desired, with display spacing as expected. Updated answer demonstrates this.